# Timer library in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm looking for an open source timer library written in C. The library should have Timer callback functions, etc.

On searching I see **POSIX timers** or **setitimer()**, which use a signal based approach that may lead to problems in multithreaded code.

Say if I use POSIX Timers inside threaded code, the signals won't be reaching to the correct place. If I use several timers in a process then each one should use different signals. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: It's generally helpful to explain why this is getting down-voted / closed.

Comment: This is getting close votes because it _will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion_. Do some research, try using one or more candidates, ask if you have problems with them. Or ask, for example, _can I use POSIX setitimer in multithreaded code_ ... that's a good question

Comment: I answered the question about using POSIX timers in threaded code. It can be done, and I showed the relevant part of the documentation.

Comment: A program may create multiple interval timers using timer_create(). See my answer.

Comment: I ended up using libdispatch which is available on macOS and has also been ported to multiple other systems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are running Linux, I would recommend using the built in POSIX timer API's.

```
int timer_create(clockid_t clockid, struct sigevent *sevp, timer_t *timerid);
```

Here is a link to some [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) showing how to use POSIX timers which provide support for callback functions.

Regarding multiple timers in a process, the documentation says this:

```
   A program may create multiple interval timers using timer_create().

   Timers are not inherited by the child of a fork(2), and are disarmed and
   deleted during an execve(2).

   The kernel preallocates a "queued real-time signal" for each timer created
   using timer_create().  Consequently, the number of timers is limited by the
   RLIMIT_SIGPENDING resource limit (see setrlimit(2)).
```

**Note that POSIX timers can be used in a threaded application by setting up notification using SIGEV_THREAD_ID as shown below:**

```
The sevp.sigev_notify field can have the following values:

       SIGEV_NONE
              Don't asynchronously notify when the timer expires.  Progress of the
              timer can be monitored using timer_gettime(2).

       SIGEV_SIGNAL
              Upon timer expiration, generate the signal sigev_signo for the process.
              See sigevent(7) for general details.  The si_code field of the
              siginfo_t structure will be set to SI_TIMER.  At any point in time, at
              most one signal is queued to the process for a given timer; see
              timer_getoverrun(2) for more details.

       SIGEV_THREAD
              Upon timer expiration, invoke sigev_notify_function as if it were the
              start function of a new thread.  See sigevent(7) for details.

       SIGEV_THREAD_ID (Linux-specific)
              As for SIGEV_SIGNAL, but the signal is targeted at the thread whose ID
              is given in sigev_notify_thread_id, which must be a thread in the same
              process as the caller.  The sigev_notify_thread_id field specifies a
              kernel thread ID, that is, the value returned by clone(2) or gettid(2).
              This flag is only intended for use by threading libraries.
```

Comment: If i use POSIX Timers inside a threaded code ,the signals wont be reaching to the correct place.If i use several timers in a process then each one should use different signals.Any other alternatives ?

Comment: You can setup notification to be thread aware using SIGEV_THREAD_ID. So the timer signal will go to the thread ID you wish it to go to.

Comment: "`Here is a link to some documentation showing how to use POSIX timers which provide support for callback functions`" - where? I can't see any mention of callback functions

Comment: @Mawg Through the `sevp.sigev_notify` member of the sevp struct.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: See `SIGEV_THREAD` for `sevp.sigev_notify`

Answer (score 7):

The Linux way of doing it would be via [timerfd_create](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timerfd_create) which integrates nicely with epoll-based event loops (and thereby avoiding the restrictions of signal handlers)

Comment: Would like to know the resolution accuracy of timefd.

Comment: It's exactly the same as timer_create as the underlying infrastructure is the same - it's just the notification interface that's different.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to use with epoll_wait(), yet I think I spent an hour researching timers and epoll without noticing this mentioned by anyone else. Much obliged.

Answer (score -6):

This is far to simple to create a library for.

example:

```
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    time_t start,end;
    double dif;
    double duration=40f; //duration of timer
    bool loop=true;
    while(loop==true)
    {
        time(&start);
        if(dif==duration)
        {
            /*callback*/
            dif=0;
        }
        //do stuff
        time(&end);
        dif+=difftime(end,start);
    }
{
```

Comment: Simple solution, but it doesn't really provide a proper callback mechanism.

Comment: Wouldn't be hard to make it do so. I was just throwing the idea out there.

Comment: The whole point of using a timer callback is to avoid checking the time at every iteration! -1